# Access List from another class

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, dictionary, scope

can anyone tell me how to create a list in one class and access it from another?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
public class MyClass {

    private List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    public List<string> GetList()
    {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

You can have any anything there instead of string.
Now you can make an object of `MyClass` and can access the public method where you have implemented to return `myList`.

```
public class CallingClass {

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    public void GetList()
    {
        List<string> calledList = myClass.GetList();
        ///More code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you for this succinct example.

Comment: Thank you, this is most usefull and helpfull answer!

Comment: But each time you do MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); in another class the list is empty again.... how can you access MyClass existing list with content in another class ?

Answer (score 11):

To create a list call the list constructor:

```
class Foo
{
    private List<Item> myList = new List<Item>();
}
```

To make it accessible to other classes add a public property which exposes it.

```
class Foo
{
    private List<Item> myList = new List<Item();

    public List<Item> MyList
    {
        get { return myList; }
    }
}
```

To access the list from another class you need to have a reference to an object of type `Foo`. Assuming that you have such a reference and it is called `foo` then you can write `foo.MyList` to access the list.

You might want to be careful about exposing Lists directly. If you only need to allow read only access consider exposing a [`ReadOnlyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) instead.

Comment: @Brian, Create a Object of Foo in the accessing class as Foo objFoo=new Foo(); and then access MyList as List<Item> myList1=objFoo.myList;

Comment: How does it work? When you call it in another class it will be an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

In case you need a List declared as static property

```
class ListShare 
{
    public static List<String> DataList { get; set; } = new List<String>();
}

class ListUse
{
    public void AddData()
    {
        ListShare.DataList.Add("content ...");
    }

    public void ClearData()
    {
        ListShare.DataList.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: i was able to use this answer ,i couldn't quite understand the first, but i did make some changes.

Comment: class ListUse
{
    public void AddData(string data2add)
    {
        ListShare.DataList.Add(data2add);
    }
}

class Program{
static void Main(){

Listuse dataAdd = new ListUse();
string data2add = "CONTENT";


ListUse.AddData(data2add);