# c# List print from other class

Tags: c#, list

I'm doing console app for my studies . I have just started c# programming. I have class Document,Book,Tom,Newspaper. 
I created class DocumentList which store all Documents i have 
method there to add single document. And there is a problem i want to  access this List in my console class. I run debug and adding to List is correct.
I was looking in internet for example this one

[Access List from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717028/access-list-from-another-class)
but no success :

program even dont go into  this if else statements.Probably i'm doing wrong in this lines   because calledList is empty in display Method.

### Console Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using zad1;

    namespace Konsolowa
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public DocumentList lista = new DocumentList();

        private int choice;

        public Program()
        { }

        public void options(int wybor)
        {
            Program a = new Program();

            Book bk = new Book();
            Console.WriteLine("1. Add");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Display ");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Release");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Delete");

            if (wybor == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your choose adding: ");
                Console.WriteLine("Title: ");
                String Title = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Press: ");
                String Press = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Author: ");
                String Author = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("SiteCounter: ");
                int SiteCounter = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("name: ");
                Console.WriteLine("Year of Publish: ");
                int year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Document w = new Book(Title, Press, SiteCounter, Author, year);

                try
                {
                    lista.AddDocument(w);
                }
                catch (TitleExistException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");

                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Do you want to continue ?");
                wybor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            if (wybor == 2)
            {
                a.display();
                Console.Write("Do you want to continue ? ");
                wybor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            if (wybor == 3)
            {
                Console.Write("Give title ");
                String Title = (Console.ReadLine());
                lista.RemovyByTitle(Title);
                Console.Write("List");
                a.display();
                Console.Write("Do you want to continue ?");
                wybor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        public void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List");

            List<Document> calledList = lista.Documents;

            Console.WriteLine(calledList.Count());
            foreach (Document p in calledList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("omg");

                Console.WriteLine(p.Title);
                Console.WriteLine(p.SiteCounter);
                Console.WriteLine(p.Press);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program a = new Program();
            int choice;

            Console.Write("Your Choice? ");
            choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            a.options(choice);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

### Document Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace zad1
{
    public abstract class Document
    {
        public Document(String Title, String Press, int SiteCounter)
        {
            this.Title = Title;
            this.Press = Press;
            this.SiteCounter = SiteCounter;
        }

        public Document()
        { }

        public String Title { get; set; }

        public String Press { get; set; }

        public int SiteCounter { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

### DocumentList class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace zad1
{

    public class DocumentList
    {
        private List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();
        private List<Tom> toms = new List<Tom>();
        private List<Czasopismo> czasopismo = new List<Czasopismo>();
        private List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

        public List<Document> Documents { get { return documents; } }

        public List<Book> Book { get { return Book; } }

        public List<Tom> Toms { get { return Toms; } }

        public List<Czasopismo> Czasopismo { get { return Czasopismo; } }

        public DocumentList()
        { }

        public Document RemovyByTitle(String Title)
        {
            Document k = documents.Single(kk => kk.Title.Equals(Title));
            documents.Remove(k);

            return k;
        }

        public void AddDocument(Document document)
        {
            if (documents.Contains(document))
            {
                throw new TitleExistException("Dodanie dokumentu o tytule ktory juz istnieje");
            }

            documents.Add(document);
        }

        public void AddTom(Tom tom)
        {
            foreach (Tom t in toms)
            {
                if (toms.Equals(t.nrTom))
                {
                    throw new NrOfTomExistException("Dodanie dokumentu o tytule ktory juz istnieje");
                }
                else if (t.nrTom > t.allTom)
                {
                    throw new nrTomBiggerThanSerieException("Wiekszy niz niz seria");
                }
            }

            toms.Add(tom);
        }

        public void AddBook(Book book)
        {
            foreach (Book b in books)
            {
                if (b.YearOfPublish < 1440)
                {
                    throw new YearException("Czlowieku nie istnieje druk");
                }
            }

            books.Add(book);
        }

        public List<Document> SearchWithPhares(String Phrase)
        {
            List<Document> temp = new List<Document>();
            foreach (Document d in documents)
            {
                if (d.Title.Contains(Phrase))
                    temp.Add(d);
            }
            return temp;
        }

        public List<Czasopismo> ListWithFreq(Freq freq)
        {
            List<Czasopismo> temp = new List<Czasopismo>();
            foreach (Document d in documents)
            {
                if ((d.Equals(freq) && d is Czasopismo))
                    temp.Add((Czasopismo)d);
            }
            return temp;
        }

        public List<Tom> AllTomForTitle(String Title)
        {
            List<Tom> temp = new List<Tom>();
            foreach (Document d in documents)
            {
                if ((d.Title == Title && d is Tom))
                    temp.Add((Tom)d);
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

### Others CLasses

```
namespace zad1
{
    public class Book : Document
    {
        public Book()
        { }

        public String Author { get; set; }

        public int YearOfPublish { get; set; }

        public Book(String Title, String Press, int SiteCounter, String Author, int YearOfPublish)
            : base(Title, Press, SiteCounter)
        {
            this.Author = Author;
            this.YearOfPublish = YearOfPublish;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Author {0} yearofpublish {1} ", base.ToString());
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace zad1
{
    public class Czasopismo : Document
    {
        public int Nmb { get; set; }

        public Czasopismo(String Title, String Press, int SiteCounter, int Nmb, Freq freq)
            : base(Title, Press, SiteCounter)
        {
            this.Nmb = Nmb;
        }
    }
}

namespace zad1
{
    public enum Freq
    {
        None,
        Week,
        Month
    }
}

namespace zad1
{
    public class Tom : Book
    {
        public int nrTom { get; set; }

        public int allTom { get; set; }

        public Tom(String Title, String Press, int SiteCounter, String Author, int YearOfPublish, int nrTom, int allTom)
            : base(Title, Press, SiteCounter, Author, YearOfPublish)
        {
            this.nrTom = nrTom;
            this.allTom = allTom;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("nrTomu {0} all Tom {1} ", base.ToString());
        }
    } 
}

namespace zad1
{
    [Serializable]
    public class TitleExistException : ApplicationException
    {
        public TitleExistException()
        { }

        public TitleExistException(string message)
            : base(message)
        { }

        public TitleExistException(string message, Exception inner)
            : base(message, inner)
        { }

        protected TitleExistException(
          System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
          System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context) { }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class NrOfTomExistException : Exception
    {
        public NrOfTomExistException()
        { }

        public NrOfTomExistException(string message)
            : base(message)
        { }

        public NrOfTomExistException(string message, Exception inner)
            : base(message, inner)
        { }

        protected NrOfTomExistException(
          System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
          System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context) { }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class nrTomBiggerThanSerieException : Exception
    {
        public nrTomBiggerThanSerieException()
        { }

        public nrTomBiggerThanSerieException(string message)
            : base(message)
        { }

        public nrTomBiggerThanSerieException(string message, Exception inner)
            : base(message, inner)
        { }

        protected nrTomBiggerThanSerieException(
          System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
          System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context) { }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class YearException : Exception
    {
        public YearException()
        { }

        public YearException(string message)
            : base(message)
        { }

        public YearException(string message, Exception inner)
            : base(message, inner)
        { }

        protected YearException(
          System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
          System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about where you are having trouble. There's a lot of code here, and your problem statement is very vague.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't come close to compiling.

Comment: I've fixed it into something I think you wan't and answered the question, please submit code that actually compiles or a coherent question or it'll just get closed. Hope I helped, the DocumentList class is entirely un needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should help, This is an entire console application you can paste into visual studio and get running.

Notice that the class Book inherits from Document, the base keyword lets you initialise the properties in the superclass.

I have setup the properties so they can be initialised. Notice you will need to cast the document back to Book to access properties that are not on Document should you need to access those (I suggest you look up casting elsewhere as this is almost definatly homework).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string title = "The title of the document";
            const string press = "The press of the document";
            const string author = "Some author of the document";
            const int siteCounter = 10;
            Document w = new Book(title, press, siteCounter, author, null);

            List<Document> docList = new List<Document>();

            try
            {
                docList.Add(w);
            }
            catch (TitleExistException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);

            }

            DisplayListOfDocuments(docList);
        }

        public static void DisplayListOfDocuments(List<Document> docList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List");

            Console.WriteLine(docList.Count);
            foreach (Document p in docList)
            {
                if (docList.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("List Empty");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.Title);
                    Console.WriteLine(p.SiteCounter);
                    Console.WriteLine(p.Press);

                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



    }

    public class Book : Document
    {
        public Book(string title, string press, int siteCounter, string author, string rok)
            : base(title, press, siteCounter)
        {
            Rok = rok;
        }

        public string Rok { get; set; }
    }

    public class Document
    {
        public Document(string title, string press, int siteCounter)
        {
            Title = title;
            Press = press;
            SiteCounter = siteCounter;
        }

        public Document()
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
        }

        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String Press { get; set; }
        public int SiteCounter { get; set; }
    }

    public class TitleExistException : Exception
    {
    }
}
```

NB: I removed DocumentList as it was entirely unnecessary.