# C# access List after return

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm a noob with C# but I'm trying to create a simple code for connecting to my mysql database (most of the code I got from google). So I have this part where something from the database is selected and stored in a list. Now I want to access this from another class but I have no idea how to do that and I couldn't find the answer on google either (this thread also didn't worked for me: [Access List from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717028/access-list-from-another-class)) so can anyone please help me?

Here's the particular code:

```
public List<string>[] Select()
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM users";

            //Create a list to store the result
            List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
            list[0] = new List<string>();
            list[1] = new List<string>();
            list[2] = new List<string>();

            //Open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Create Command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //Read the data and store them in the list
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    list[0].Add(dataReader["id"] + "");
                    list[1].Add(dataReader["test"] + "");
                    list[2].Add(dataReader["balance"] + "");
                }

                //close Data Reader
                dataReader.Close();

                //close Connection
                this.CloseConnection();

                //return list to be displayed
                return list;
            }
            else
            {
                return list;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you show how you would *want* to access it?

Comment: In an other class I would like to call list[0],list[1] and list[2] and store those each in separate strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously I think the way you've structured the data here, is strange.

You're creating an array of a objects, where the object is a List of string:

```
List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
```

You want to be thinking in objects; create a class that represents the data; in this case *User*. Something like this:

```
public class User 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public string Balance { get; set; }
}
```

So personally I'd do the following:

- Create a class that represents each user record.
- Create a variable to hold a list of users.
- Read from MySql and assign each record to a new User object.
- Add the user to the list.
- Return the list.

Change the return type of your Select method to be `List<User>` like this:

```
public List<User> Select() {
```

Then amend the rest of the method to create and return list of users.

```
public List<User> Select() {

    List<User> list = new List<User>();

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            User user = new User();

            user.Id = dataReader["id"].toString();
            user.Test = dataReader["test"].toString();
            user.Balance = dataReader["balance"].toString();

            list.Add(user);
        }

        dataReader.Close();

        this.CloseConnection();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Then you can use your list something like this:

```
ClassThatContainsSelectMethod yourDBObject = new ClassThatContainsSelectMethod();

List<User> users = yourDBObject.Select();

foreach (User user in users) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.Id, user.Test, user.Balance); 
}
```

This code of course could be better structured with factories and error/null checks but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Like I said I'm a noob in C# so I'm mostly reliable on Google so I didn't know if this was the right way to do it. I got an error in your code though on the lines user.Id = dataReader["id"]; etc : Cannot convert source type 'object' to target type 'string'

Comment: At this line 'List<User> users = yourDBObject.Select();' it also says cannot access non-static field in static context??

Comment: Yes this code is untested - regards the assignment line `user.Id = dataReader["id"]`,  add `.toString()` - I've updated the answer to show this.  `dataReader["..."] retuns an object so you need to cast it to the same type that your assigning to - in this case a string.

Comment: Regards this `List<User> users = yourDBObject.Select();` - its unclear from your code example what the class containing the `Select()` looks like.  You need to create an instance of the class - I've added example to the answer.

Comment: Also if your class has specific constructor then remember to pass the correct parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Class containing your original method:

```
    public class YourClass
    {
        public List<string>[] Select()
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM users";

            //Create a list to store the result
            List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];


            ///
            /// you original implementation here 
            ///
        }
    }
```

Here Class where you use your method:

```
 public class UsingClass
   {
    private YourClass _yourClass;
    public UsingClass()
    {
       _yourClass = new YourClass();
    }

    private void SomeUsingMethod()
    {
       List<string>[] list =  _yourClass.Select();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, it worked perfectly. I was wondering, how do I call these classes in the static void Main() to write the list in the console?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to share data from classes.One of them is defining a property for the desired list and then accsess it. Lets say you have class data

```
class DataString 
{
    private string data = "data";

    public string Data
    {
        get { return data}
        set { data = value }
    }
}
```

and

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DataString dataStr = new DataString();

        // Assigning the dataStr property causes the 'set' accessor to be called.
        dataStr.Data = "some string";

        // Evaluating the Hours property causes the 'get' accessor to be called.
        System.Console.WriteLine(dataStr.Data); //this will display "some string"
    }
}
```

You could the same way create a list class with your desired functions and variables and modiffy them with methods and access them with properties.