# XNA/C# Edit list<> from another class

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I have a project in class where I decided to make a DX Ball game in XNA, and have goten along quite well but now I'm stuck.

I have created a list of "bricks", that is rectangles, for my sprites to be positioned by and for my ball to collide with.
I have an idea to let all ball logic be in the ball class so now the fun part that I need help with. How to edit this list when the ball collides with one of the bricks. I want to delete the brick that has been hit, and I figure that will be okay since they are declared as individual bricks with individual coordinates.

I have found this question, and it answers the part of how to get things out of a list but not how to edit it.
[Access List from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717028/access-list-from-another-class)

I was thinking about writing a Boolean function in the ball update field, since i don't need it to calculate every time it updates a frame. When collision is true it can cal the function that iterates through the list of bricks and delete the one the ball hit.

I'm not sure what I need to show from my ball class so there might be some if needed later on.

```
 public struct BoundingBrick
 {
     public Vector2 brickPosision;
     public double BrickW;
     public double BrickH;

 }     

 public BoundingBrick boundingBrick = new BoundingBrick();

 boundingBrick.BrickW = 50;
 boundingBrick.BrickH = 20;
 boundingBrick.brickPosision.X = 50;
 boundingBrick.brickPosision.Y = 50;

 bricks = new List<Rectangle>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++)
            {
                 bricks.Add(new Rectangle((int)boundingBrick.brickPosision.X + j * 50, (int)boundingBrick.brickPosision.Y + i * 20, (int)boundingBrick.BrickW, (int)boundingBrick.BrickH));
            }
        }
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to SO. I would advise you to add a boolean variable, something like `Visible` to your `BoundingBrick`struct. Then, instead of having a `List<Rectangle>` you'd better have a `List<BoundingBrick>`, and build your rectangle after having the list populated. I'm not an xna expert, so I can't help you further..

Comment: RemoveAt(index) removes the element at the given index. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But how to edit from another class?

Comment: You could make brick list static field. Like this: public static List<BoundingBrick> bricks = new List<BoundingBricks>(); Then in Ball class You could access brick list with BoundingBricks.bricks and iterate through it, removing ones that collides.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this:

List bricks
Rectangle ball;

```
foreach (BoundingBrick brick in bricks.ToArray())
    {                       
         if (ball.rect.Intersects(brick.rect))
         {
            ball.CollideEffect();
            brick.TakeDamage();
         } 
    }
```

and in the TakeDamage Class from the brick:

```
public void TakeDamage(List<BoundingBrick> bricks)
{
      lives -= 1;
      if (lives <= 0)
      {
            bricks.remove(this)        
      }  
}
```

The 'ToArray()' part will prevent it from crashing in the list.