# How to read a List from one class in another

Tags: c#, console-application

Ok, so in a console application I'm working on, I have a list (myList) in Class01

```
class Class01
{
    public List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    public void _addsList()
    {
        myList.Add("0001Test01");
        myList.Add("0002Test02");
        myList.Add("0003Test03");
        myList.Add("0004Test04");

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myList[i] + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

and I need to read that list in Class02

```
class Class02
{
    public void _callList()
    {
        var class02 = new Class01();
        string wits2;

        List<string> buffer = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < class02.myList.Count; i++)
        {
            wits2 = class02.myList[i].Substring(0, 4);
            Console.WriteLine(class02.myList[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

The Output of this program should write this to the Console:

0001Test01,

0002Test02,

0003Test03,

0004Test04,

0001

0002

0003

0004

Now I've seen GetList used to do this

```
public class MyClass {

    private List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    public List<string> GetList()
    {
        return myList;
    }
 } 


public class CallingClass {

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    public void GetList()
    {
        List<string> calledList = myClass.GetList();
        ///More code here...
    }
}
```

But I for the life of me can not get this to work. I don't know if I'm missing a namespace or what. I don't even know if GetList works in console application.

So I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks-

Comment: What is `can not get this to work`? Also, you are not putting any values into `myList` you return from `GetList` of  `MyClass`.

Comment: The First 2 blocks of code is mine work. The other 2 are from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717028/access-list-from-another-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not totally clear from your question what is not working. But I suspect you need to put values in the list. If you mean it is not displaying anything in the console try this:

```
 var class02 = new Class01();
 string wits2;

 class02._addsList();
```

**EDIT:** after reading your comment, I think this will remedy it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < class02.myList.Count; i++)
{
    wits2 = class02.myList[i].Substring(0, 4);
    Console.WriteLine(class02.myList[i]);
    buffer.Add(wits2);//Add it to list declared in this function
}
```

NOTE: If you mean you are getting output when calling `_addsList` on class object the make sure that you have called this function once before using an object of `Class01`. From second block of code for `Class02` you are not calling `_addsList` function on object of `Class01`.

Comment: (Note to self: Get better at wording these)
My problem is Class02 can not read the List from Class01
Class01 Writes the full list
Class02 is suppose to read the list in Class01 and store only the first 4 digits in it's own List. So "0001Test1" is save as "0001" in the new List

Comment: Are you getting any exception etc.? Are both classes defined in the same project. Try declaring `class01` as `internal`.

Answer (score 0):

On your Class02:

```
        var class02 = new Class01();
        class02._addsList(); //Add this on your declaration
        string wits2;
```

Then change the variable you are passing on your Console.WriteLine:

```
List<string> buffer = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < class02.myList.Count; i++)
        {
            wits2 = class02.myList[i].Substring(0, 4);
            //Console.WriteLine(class02.myList[i]); //Remove this
            Console.WriteLine(wits2);  //Use wits2 instead since this is what you get on your Substring
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think most important thing you are missing is that your classes are not marked as public

so please add public before class declarations as below

```
    public class Class02
    {
    ......
```

One more thing, to get your required output, in your class02 you are assigning substring to 'wits' variable but not printing it. You are instead passing value from list to Console.Writeline.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to TheVillageIdiot. I got this working now. So thank you. My code looks like this now:

```
public class Class01
{
    public List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    public void _addsList()
    {
        myList.Add("0001Test01");
        myList.Add("0002Test02");
        myList.Add("0003Test03");
        myList.Add("0004Test04");            
    }
}

class Class02
{
    public void _callList()
    {
        var class01 = new Class01();
        class01._addsList(); //<--- Had to add this line

        for (int i = 0; i < class01.myList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(class01.myList[i] + ",");
        }

        string wits2;

        List<string> buffer = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < class01.myList.Count; i++)
        {
            wits2 = class01.myList[i].Substring(0, 4);
            Console.WriteLine(wits2);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

For toughs who didn't understand the problem, Class02 could not read the List in Class01.

Thanks for the Help!